# nightwatch.js how to save elements to list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

In Java there is a function `findElements` which I'm using like this:

```
public static List<WebElement> listIGP (WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
    elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id,'bg_widget_Asset_')]")));
    return elementList;
}
```

Is it possible to do sth like this with nightwatch?

Comment: http://nightwatchjs.org/api/elements.html That should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this in nightwatch :

```
var listofelements; 
    ...
      browser.elements('xpath','path_to_selector',function (elements){
        listofelements=elements.value;

    })
```

console.log(listofelements) should give you :

```
{
ELEMENT : 'xx'
ELEMENT : 'xx'
ELEMENT : 'xx'
ELEMENT : 'xx'
ELEMENT : 'xx'
ELEMENT : 'xx'
...
}
```